# AngularJS custom directive for a ng-indeterminate attribute on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

Here is a directive that handles the indeterminate state on checkboxes:

```js
.directive('ngIndeterminate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            attributes.$observe('ngIndeterminate', function(value) {
                $(element).prop('indeterminate', value == "true");
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Then, for example with these data:

```js
$scope.data = [
    {name: 'foo', displayed: 2, total: 4},
    {name: 'bar', displayed: 3, total: 3}
];
```

You would simply need:

```xml
<ul ng-repeat="item in data">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-indeterminate="{{item.displayed > 0 && item.displayed < item.total}}" ng-checked="item.displayed > 0" />
        {{item.name}} ({{item.displayed}}/{{item.total}})
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to write the ng-indeterminate expression without the double-curly notation, just as the native ng-checked one?

```xml
ng-indeterminate="item.displayed > 0 && item.displayed < item.total"
```

I tried:

```js
.directive('ngIndeterminate', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            attributes.$observe('ngIndeterminate', function(value) {
                $(element).prop('indeterminate', $compile(value)(scope));
            });
        }
    };
})
```

But I get the following error:

```
Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QFL6/) you can play with.

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/d9rG7/1/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, you do not need to wrap `element` in jQuery if you load jQuery **before** angular. So you would then never need to use `$(element)` inside your directives and instead can use `element` directly as angular will automatically wrap `element` as a jQuery object.

For your example, you don't actually even need jQuery, so the answer provided below does not rely on jQuery at all.

As to your question, you can `$watch` your attribute values, angular automatically returns the compiled attribute value. So the following works as you would expect:

```
.directive('ngIndeterminate', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$watch(attributes['ngIndeterminate'], function (value) {
                element.prop('indeterminate', !!value);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9rG7/5/): http://jsfiddle.net/d9rG7/5/

Comment: You are relying on jQuery, as `.prop` is jQuery method, and `element` is a jQuery object anyway.  You may strip it by doing `element[0].indeterminate = !!value`, but I am not sure if this is an improvement.

Comment: @punund `.prop` is part of jqLite, so no need for jQuery https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: BTW, ng-indeterminate is now part of angular-ui utils: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Answer (score 5):

Use `scope.$eval` and `element.prop` directly to change attribute:

```
.directive('ngIndeterminate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            attributes.$observe('ngIndeterminate', function(value) {
                element.prop('indeterminate', scope.$eval(value));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/d9rG7/6/)

---

By using `attributes.$observe` you can only catch attribute changes that contains interpolation (i.e., {{}}'s). You should use `scope.$watch` that can observe/watch an "expression". So, @Beyers answer is more correct i think. Thx for noting @Chi_Row

Comment: $observe doesn't seem to notice the changes.  Any reason why?  [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/YzT2W/1/)

Comment: okay, so $observe is not noticing the changes because ngInderterminate attribute contains no interpolated values.  So even though the object is changing $observe will not fire.  $watch is the correct way to notice the change in this case.